# greasemonkey insert javascript

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have a bookmarklet, clicking the bookmarklet includes a PHP script (evaluated as a JavaScript file) to the page few table values and select values passed as GET parameters. The PHP script writes the page data to the MySQL database, and outputs a success message that is treated as JavaScript code and executed by the browser. Is there any possibility to do this using greasemonkey and call this function when a existing button is clicked on the web page.

I wrote the above bookmarklet inspired by this tutorial.

http://tutorialzine.com/2010/04/simple-bookmarking-app-php-javascript-mysql/

This is the bookmarklet code:

```
(function () {
var jsScript = document.createElement('script');

jsScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');

jsScript.setAttribute('src', '/bookmark.php?url=' + encodeURIComponent(location.href) + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(document.title));

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jsScript);
})();
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do this a lot.
Here's a script that should work for you, just edit the `@include` statement to match the pages the Greasemonkey script will be used on.

Also, `/bookmark.php` will probably have to be changed to a full address, rather than a relative one.

```
//
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Adding a live button
// @namespace       http://www.google.com/
// @description     Adds a custom bookmarking button.
// @include         http://www.google.com/*
// ==/UserScript==
//


function LocalMain ()
{

    /*--- Create a button in a container div.  It will be styled and postioned with CSS.
    */
    var zNode       = document.createElement ('div');
    zNode.innerHTML = '<form id="idMyForm" method="get" action="">'
                    + '  <p><input type="submit" id="idMySubmitBtn" value="Bookmark it"></p>'
                    + '</form>'
                    ;
    zNode.setAttribute ('id', 'idBookMarkBtnContainer');

    document.body.appendChild (zNode);

    zNode.addEventListener ("submit", BookmarkButtonAction,   false);
}


function BookmarkButtonAction (zEvent)
{
    zEvent.preventDefault();

    var jsScript    = document.createElement('script');

    jsScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');

    /*--- Is "/bookmark.php" going to work on all target pages?
    */
    jsScript.setAttribute('src', '/bookmark.php?url=' + encodeURIComponent(location.href) + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(document.title));

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jsScript);

    return false;
}


window.addEventListener ("load", LocalMain, false);
//LocalMain();


GM_addStyle
(
   '#idBookMarkBtnContainer                         \
    {                                               \
        position:               absolute;           \
        top:                    0;                  \
        left:                   0;                  \
                                                    \
        background:             orange;             \
        border:                 3px double #999999; \
        margin:                 5px;                \
        opacity:                0.9;                \
        z-index:                222;                \
                                                    \
        min-height:             10px;               \
        min-width:              20px;               \
        padding:                5px 20px;           \
    }                                               \
    #idMySubmitBtn                                  \
    {                                               \
        cursor:                 pointer;            \
    }                                               \
   '
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make this an actual named function, not a closure (right in Greasemonkey script), then add that function as an onclick= event of said button, straight inline just below the actual function.

Although, hijacking pre-existing webpage buttons for that purpose is not safe nor an officially blessed method - it's much better and easier to attach it to a Greasemonkey [Menu Command](http://diveintogreasemonkey.org/api/gm_registermenucommand.html) and launch it from there (rightclick the small monkey icon for the menu).